# efficiently loading jquery and javascript files in django templates

Tags: jquery, django, performance, load

In one of my django projects i am using lots of custom jquery scripts and lots of open source jquery plugins. Now if i load all the jquery scripts in my base template, I will be loading a lot of unused javascript code in the templates which do not require any/some of the jquery files that have been loaded which will affect the page load time of that particular template.

So, The current approach i am taking is

- Load the basic jquery scripts in the base template (ones that are required by each template)
- Define a block for js in the base template and selectively load needed javascripts for each templates.e.g `{% block selective_js %}{% endblock selective_js %}`

The above approach works well, but the only problem I see is a lot of code repetition in the templates. Say for example:

- I have the following javascript files

  ```
  <script type="text/javascript" src="{{ STATIC_URL }}js/jquery.1.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="{{ STATIC_URL }}js/jquery.2.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="{{ STATIC_URL }}js/jquery.3.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="{{ STATIC_URL }}js/jquery.4.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="{{ STATIC_URL }}js/jquery.5.js"></script>
  ```
- Now in more than one templates, I need all the above mentioned javascript files included and also want to initialize some of the methods within the mentioned scripts. So currently, I have to do this in all the templates:

  ```
  {% block selective_js %}

      <script type="text/javascript" src="{{ STATIC_URL }}js/jquery.1.js"></script>
      <script type="text/javascript" src="{{ STATIC_URL }}js/jquery.2.js"></script>
      <script type="text/javascript" src="{{ STATIC_URL }}js/jquery.3.js"></script>
      <script type="text/javascript" src="{{ STATIC_URL }}js/jquery.4.js"></script>
      <script type="text/javascript" src="{{ STATIC_URL }}js/jquery.5.js"></script>

      <!-- Initialize Methods -->
      <script type="text/javascript">
          $(document).ready(function() {
              $('some_element').initializeScript();
          });
      </script>

  {% endblock selective_js %}
  ```

Which means there is a lot of code repetition within the templates.

#### Question:

How can I prevent repeating code without having to load unused javascript code in an efficient manner ?

Comment: Include them in the base template, but minify or [compress them](https://github.com/jezdez/django_compressor). That way they only need to be downloaded once (with one single request) and will be in the cache in subsequent requests.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

Define a block in your parent template where you include your "default" JavaScript files and then extend the block as needed:

```
# base.html

{% block js %}
    <script src="{{ STATIC_URL }}js/jquery.1.js"></script>
    <script src="{{ STATIC_URL }}js/jquery.2.js"></script>
    <script src="{{ STATIC_URL }}js/jquery.3.js"></script>
    <script src="{{ STATIC_URL }}js/jquery.4.js"></script>
    <script src="{{ STATIC_URL }}js/jquery.5.js"></script>
{% endblock %}


# child.html

{% extends "base.html %}

{% block js %}
    {{ block.super }} {# includes previous content in block #}
    {# view-specific imports here #}
{% endblock %}
```

This will prevent repetition in your templates. Check out: [template inheritance](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/templates/language/#id1) for more information about templates and inheritance.

You can use [django-compressor](https://github.com/jezdez/django_compressor) to combine and minify CSS and JS imports and cache them for efficient loading.