# which django authocomplete should I use?

Tags: django

I have a form which has input as name. It search the lastname and firstname field in a database. I need to autocomplete when users type the name.
I see there's several django autocomplete package. Which one should I use?
Is django-autocomplete-light a easy one?

I followed that tutorial, but has error even at the beginning, and it seems hard to understand. Thanks for any suggestion!

Answer (score 0):

Here is my answer to how to set up the bootstrap autocomplete, its not to dificult to set up:

[How to autocomplete a search form?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35534879/how-to-autocomplete-a-search-form/35540795#35540795)