# Loading JavaScript files selectively in Django

Tags: javascript, jquery, django, performance

I have `Post` model for a blog app in Django. It has a field named `body`. In posts, I may use Latex so I need to use `MathJax.js`. In some posts, I add code snippet, so I use `highlight.js`. In some I use both, in some I use none of them.

I want to load the relevant javascript depending on the `body` field of the `Post` model (similar to [THIS](https://stackoverflow.com/q/16691588/2275286)). How can I make the relevant .js file(s) to load automatically?

I know that I can add an indicator field like `hasLatex` (`True`, `False`) or `hasCode` (`True`, `False`). But I'm lazy, I want `Post.body` to be automatically scanned and only relevant js files loaded.

Comment: I would just load them both by default, they will get cached by a browser and loaded at most once per user anyway, not much gain in turning them on/off after that. If you still want dynamic js includes - you need to add those boolean latex=yes/no fields, it's a waste to detect latex on every post view rather than during post creation/editing.

Comment: I understand the logic of wasting resources and I agree with the performance gains I would get using a dedicated boolean variable. But still I wonder whether I can do it automatically.

Answer (score 0):

Set something in your context or use a template context processor. For example I load code that handles forms if there is a `form` key is my context. For something I want on almost every page I put a no_something in my context to disable it. This is done by putting a conditional around the tag in your base template. If the variable is not there or is false it won't show.

What I also do is put my static files in lists inside of my context. JavaScript is in `context['js']` and css in `context['css']`. Those are looped through in my header. I can implement get_context_data in a base class, and all the views that extend from that will have the javascript and css files.

Comment: I couldn't see how adding `no_something` is different than adding indicator fields in `Post` model. I don't know "template context processor", I'll check that.